# Scroller not shown Flex 4 with VGroup

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, scroller

I am creating one application. In that There is one popup, in that I had used one VGroup in one Scroller.

I am dynamically adding my custom components in VGroup and removing all components at the closing of the popup and saves those components in Memory Pool.

In First step, I open a popup with numbers of components by that scroll bar appears.
Then I close the popup.

In second step, I opens a same popup instance with some less components so scroll bar does not appears and close the popup.

And now when I open popup with more components again scrollbar not appears.
So whenever popup is once opend with less components, scrollbar disappears.

Pls help me...

Here is the full code :

```
<s:Scroller id="myScroller"
        width="100%"
        height="210"
        horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
    <s:VGroup id="myContainer"
         width="100%"
         height="210" />
</s:Scroller>
```

Code for Adding Components :

```
for each(var object:MyObject in _arr)
{
    var newView:MyCustomView = MyCustomViewPool.acquire();
    myContainer.addElementAt(newView, 0);
    newView.myData = object;
}
```

Here is the code for removing components :

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < myContainer.numElements; i++)
{
    var newViewElement:IVisualElement = myContainer.getElementAt(i);
    var myViewComponent:MyCustomView = newViewElement as MyCustomView;
    MyCustomViewPool.release(myViewComponent);

}
myContainer.removeAllElements();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to set the hight on the VGroup. Just remove the assignment.

Comment: That's right: since the Scroller and the VGroup are both exactly 210px high, the VGroup is not bigger than the Scroller, hence no scrollbars.

Comment: And also with that height of VGroup it is running fine when the first time when popup is created...

Comment: clipEnableAndScrolling=true on the VGroup.